# React navigation 5 - header is not shown

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

Trying to update my app to react navigation 5 and been confronting some issues.

First of all, the header does not show up. Snips from the code:

[from App.js]

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator >
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{ title:'some title' }}/>
        <Tab.Screen name="Upload" component={UploadScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Find" component={FindScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and the style of the current screen:

```
<View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'column',justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
```

Here is a screenshot of the app on an Android emulator (and it looks the same on my phone):

[image]

As you can see, the header is not shown, the tab navgiation does not right, and so are the buttons (something changed about their background). I did not change anything in the app besides upgrading to react-navigation 5..

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tab navigators do not have header support. You have to wrap your tab navigator inside a stack navigator.

```js
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
// ... other imports

export const App = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <StackNavigator />
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const StackNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Tabs" component={TabNavigator} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}

const Tab = createTabNavigator();
const TabNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator >
            <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Upload" component={UploadScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Find" component={FindScreen} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I tried to do it and got the error 'A navigator can only contain 'Screen' components as its direct children'.

Comment: You have to put the navigator in the `component` prop of the Tab.Screen. Exemple: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators

Comment: Exactly as @RaphaelPr said, I'll add a small example.